# PythonOCC conda install broken?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Win 10 x54 Python2.7, Anaconda

I'm tryng to install the PythonOCC library with `conda install -c pythonocc pythonocc-core=0.17.3`

But it appears broken...

[image]

Is it no longer active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/dlr-sc pythonocc-core`

or

`conda install -c dlr-sc pythonocc-core=0.17.3`

Comment: `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/dlr-sc pythonocc-core` did the trick